# Highlight latex syntax in C#

Tags: c#, .net, syntax-highlighting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How Is Syntax Highlighting Built?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031154/how-is-syntax-highlighting-built)

I'm writing in C#. I have a simple RichTextBox, In which I'm writing in LaTeX.

**Question**:
How can I add LaTeX syntax highlighting in the box, so when I'm writing (in LaTeX syntax) the text will be highlighted?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Please read [faq] and [ask]

Comment: Saw this. Found a huge project. can't see how am I suppose to find something useful in it

Comment: Syntax-highlighting LaTeX requires parsing it, which requires executing it, actually, since many characters can gain special status depending on prior definitions and things like `\verb#foo#` can be defined as well which you cannot distinguish without first at least understanding the prior code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`RichTextBox` does not natively support syntax highlighting. You will have to write your own or build on [an existing one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10675/Enabling-syntax-highlighting-in-a-RichTextBox).

Comment: It means that I have to find all the keywords in LaTeX isn't it?

Comment: It means that you will have to do a lot of work.

Comment: Need a RegExp in here to help me out. But have difficulty to create one myself

Comment: You need a lot more than a RegExp. Design your project first. That will tell you what components you need.

Comment: I'm pretty much sure that this is the last piece of the puzzle. I've managed to highlight C syntax keywords. Now I want to move to the next stage and write the RexExp and see how well will it work

Comment: Then go and write the RegExp. You don't need my permission. If you are having trouble writing a RegExp, then post a new question "How do I write a RegExp that recognizes LaTeX keywords?" and show the regexp you have so far.